How to stop testing after important test failing
in need my PHPUnit testing to stop if my test fails.
No more Tests in this file and any other files.
This was my attempt. But it does not stop any further tests.
public function test_env_testing_is_existing(): void
{
    throw new \Exception('Some Exception Text');   
}

I can also configure phpunit.xml with "stopOnFailure="true".
This stops any further tests if any of my tests fail but not in particular this test.
At the end my usecase is the test if there is the proper configuration of the database for testing.
public function test_env_testing_is_existing(): void
{
    if (!file_exists(base_path('.env.testing'))) {
        
        throw new \Exception('.env.testing file does not exist in the root directory'); // Stop further tests
    }
}

If this is not configured correctly. This could lead to deleting my Database witch would be catastrophic.

Could this be done bootstrap code? It isn't really a "test", it is a validation of the underlying system.

Why not set it on the phpunit.xml, set another database name that for sure never exists, so you can never break it, it may not exist (as it is a configuration issue), but at least it will not refresh the real database. This is strictly a configuration issue

You could use the @depends feature to make every test depend on the result of the environment check, but that could get rather tedious if you have many such tests.
You could make an abstract test with a setUpBeforeClass() function that performs the environment check, then have all your tests extend that abstract, but that is also rather tedious, and unnecessarily runs the check for every test.
You could fiddle with the spelling of file names and functions to ensure that the environment check always runs first, but that is dangerous.
I would recommend adding a bootstrap to your phpunit.xml file:
<phpunit ... bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">

And then, in that file, run your checks to ensure that you're in testing mode. It's probably a good idea to check more than just the existence of the .env.test file, because somebody could put the prod database name there.
<?php

if (!file_exists('whatever')) {
    throw new Exception('Test env file must exist');
}

// Maybe check application mode too
if ($_ENV['APP_ENV'] !== 'test') {
    throw new Exception('Application mode must be test');
}

// Maybe check database name
if ($_ENV['DB_NAME'] !== 'test') {
    throw new Exception('Database name for tests must be test');
}

// Maybe check database type
if ($_ENV['DB_TYPE'] !== 'sqlite') {
    throw new Exception('Database type for tests must be sqlite');
}

Since this isn't a test, you can still have stopOnFailure="false" and it will stop here, but not for failed tests.

In my Laravel project i already have a bootstrap defined: bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php".
Im not shure if its fine to mess with that.

Just define your own bootstrap, then require_once Laravel's bootstrap from your bootstrap.
